# Force close error in device but not in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

i have created an app with music buttons.the app is running with no problem in the emulator of eclipse but as i use my samsung galaxy s for emulator i have a force down error as i press any button..this is my logcat when i press a btn:
![alt text][1]

this is my code from 56-86 line

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
           public void onClick(View v){
               if(mp2.isPlaying()==true||mp3.isPlaying()==true||mp4.isPlaying()==true||mp5.isPlaying()==true||mp6.isPlaying()==true||mp7.isPlaying()==true||mp8.isPlaying()==true||mp9.isPlaying()==true||mp10.isPlaying()==true||mp11.isPlaying()==true||mp12.isPlaying()==true)
                       {mp2.stop();
                       mp3.stop();mp4.stop();mp5.stop();mp6.stop();mp7.stop();mp8.stop();mp9.stop();mp10.stop();mp11.stop();mp12.stop();
                   try {
                    mp2.prepare();
                    mp3.prepare();
                    mp4.prepare();
                    mp5.prepare();mp6.prepare();mp7.prepare();mp8.prepare();mp9.prepare();mp10.prepare();
                    mp11.prepare();mp12.prepare();

                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                        mp.start();
                        Toast.makeText(a.this, "Eisai", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                       }
               else
               mp.start(); 
               Toast.makeText(a.this, "Eisai sto myalo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

           }      

        });
```

Comment: Did you really block out your package name from the stacktrace?

Answer (score 1):

Is your "if" statement line 58? (Assuming you've noted the line range correctly, it should be.) Set a debug breakpoint on that line, and inspect all of your mp* variables. Most likely one of them is null. As a side note, for clearer code, you might want to try using an `ArrayList<MediaPlayer>` to store all those MediaPlayer objects.

EDIT: You can find the ArrayList documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Basically:

```
List<MediaPlayer> mediaPlayers = new ArrayList<MediaPlayer>();
//I have no idea how you're currently making the MediaPlayers, 
//so modify accordingly.
mediaPlayers.add(MediaPlayer.create(Context, Uri));
```

Then, you can just use something like:

```
public void stopAllIfPlaying(ArrayList<MediaPlayer> mps) {
    for (MediaPlayer mp : mps) {
        if(mp.isPlaying()) mp.stop();
    }
}
```

And instead of your if statement and stop statements, use something like this:

```
stopAllIfPlaying(mediaPlayers);
```

Then do something similar with your `prepare` statements.

Comment: Also checking ` if (mp2.isPlaying()==true)` is horrible style. It should just be `if (mp2.isPlaying())`. Not only does ==true look weird, the method name is very clear about what it returns.

Comment: i uses the if method in order to stop a sond when i press a btn for another..could you tell me how to use arraylist?(and yes,ln 58 is if method)

Comment: The edit should give you some ideas. First, you should debug to find out which is null and why, though.

Comment: Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(olympiakos.this, R.raw.myalo);              this is how a make a mplayer

Comment: Yup, so just substitute your resources as needed.

Comment: sorry if my question is silly but i have been a little confused...how will i have to do it?

Comment: Just use the add() method as shown above. Where I have Context, Uri, use the context and uri (or resource id in your case) that you've shown me. All you're doing is creating them in an array instead of individually, that way you don't have to write down every single one any time you need to check them.

Comment: so i m writing   mediaplayers.add(MediaPlayer.create(olympiakos.this, R.raw.myalo));
  instead of           final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(olympiakos.this, R.raw.myalo);..and i have to do this for all my 12 mps,right?( i m really thanks for your help,i m junior android developer)

Comment: That should be correct; I'm not able to test any code right now, but that should do the trick. Then you can just use the foreach loops, as shown, any time you need to do any work on the entire list. The stopAllIfPlaying method should go inside your class, outside all other methods (e.g. outside of onCreate()).

Comment: List<MediaPlayer> mediaplayers = new ArrayList<MediaPlayer>();
             mediaplayers.add(MediaPlayer.create(olympiakos.this, R.raw.myalo));
             mediaplayers.add(MediaPlayer.create(olympiakos.this, R.raw.thryleole));                                                                 i have done this for my 12 songs..as now i had named the 1rst mp for example mp,the second mp2 etc...now how i will call them in the onclick method?

Comment: You can just use the index to retrieve the item. Arrays are zero-based, of course, so if you want the first item, just use mediaPlayers.get(0), which returns that MediaPlayer. Then just run operations on that.

Comment: button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
               public void onClick(View v){
                
                stopAllIfPlaying(mediaplayers);
                mediaplayers.get(0);
            
                Toast.makeText(olympiakos.this, "Eisai sto myalo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                
               }      
                 
            });                                                                   this is what i write in order to play on click the first song,but it force down..what i have to correct?

Comment: ((MediaPlayer) mediaplayers).start();                                          i added this too in the onclick but it forces down too...

Comment: Really, there's just a lot wrong with that. I don't mean this to be rude, but you should probably buy a book on Java and read through it to get more familiar with how the language works. When you call mediaPlayers.get(0), you're not actually DOING anything. It's a method which returns a MediaPlayer object, which you can then call your stop(), prepare(), start(), etc. methods on. (e.g. `mediaPlayers.get(0).start()`). In your second comment, you're trying to cast an entire list of objects into a single object. Use `get()` to pull an individual MediaPlayer, or a foreach to do group operations.

Comment: i dont get you as a rude guy.i have not a big experience with java and so i m asking..propably i should make a java repetition

Comment: Ok,now its fixed!the app is running in the emulator and i have really less code...but my problem is still the same..why does it force down in the device?

Comment: Did you ever do the original suggestion (debug and inspect)? None of the code shortening was meant to fix the problem, you still have a null object somewhere that you need to track down. Most likely your MediaPlayer(s) aren't getting created correctly.

Comment: i will do it right now..i have a little problem with prepare.i have created this public void prepareAllIfPlaying(List<MediaPlayer> mediaplayers) {     for (MediaPlayer mp : mediaplayers) {         if(mp.isPlaying()==false)try { mp.prepare(); } catch IllegalStateException e) {// TODO Auto-generated catch block e.printStackTrace();} catch (IOException e) {// TODO Auto-generated catch block e.printStackTrace(); }    }} and then i call   prepareAllIfPlaying(mediaplayers); in every onClick..where is my wrong?

Comment: please help...i m trying to set inspect but i dont see nothing

Comment: Read through a tutorial on debugging with Eclipse. You should set a breakpoint on the line that's failing. Start your app in debug mode (Debug As ... Android Application), go to your Debug perspective, and check the contents of mediaPlayers, to see if any of the MediaPlayer objects are null.

Answer (score 0):

Next time when you post a stacktrace, what happens BEFORE the NPE is a lot better than what happens after... But it's pretty obvious that `Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1)` is returning null. Make sure your XML is correct and there's actually a button there.